# 'Last Seen' not updated with JavaScript disabled

Tags: support, status-norepro, login, javascript, last-activity

For some reasons I need to have my **JavaScript disabled** in my browser. I noticed that since I made this change, my 'Last Seen' does not update even though I am logged in.
Now that Isn't much of a problem for me but I was concerned if my log in will be counted for the 'visited site for x number of days' badge. Since my last seen isnt updated I have no way to check If my log in was acknowledged.

**Edit**: Is there anyway I can find out exactly at what times I had a log in? Something like how we can check our account activity in Gmail?

Comment: Wait, you're worried about "Last seen" not updating, but you're not worried about voting, comments, and all the other jazz breaking?

Comment: No I'm not worried about that, since I expected those things to break. But I didnt think last seen would require java script, though I dont know much about this...

Comment: If you've been browsing without JS today then you've been clocked successfully on SO, SU, MSO and SF (Server Fault 16 hours ago).  Trial and error?

Comment: I had JS activated intermittently today. I think 'Seen' updates after a few minutes of actual login. Now I'm not really sure if it's broken or am I expecting it to update too fast.

Comment: Well since all the core functionality of SE requires JS it doesn't really seem necessary for other random features to degrade gracefully...and last-seen definitely seems to be something more than "we saw your IP". Dunno what they're doing but JS certainly seems involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We update your "seen" information roughly once every half-hour, on any request you make to the site.

While an ajax request might do this update, there's nothing intrinsically JavaScript-y about this functionality.

Comment: So even if I log in and I notice my 'seen' isnt updated, I can be sure my log in has been acknowledged by the system?